# What is the height of this pyramid?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Let $W$ be the point in the base $(XYZ)$ of the pyramid such that $VW$ and $WZ$ are perpendicular.

$XYZ$ is a right triangle and $XZ$ is perpendicular to $YZ$.

What is the height of the pyramid? My book says it is $VZ$, but I think it is $VW$.

**Context**: The problem is actually to find the volume of the pyramid given $YZ$, $XY$ and $VZ$. I got it, but I was wondering why the book called $VZ$ the "height" of the pyramid.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. (1) What centre do you talk about? Centroid? Incentre? Orthocentre? (2) The height of a pyramid is the segment through v and which is perpendicular to the base XYZ at some point, not necessary at a center.

Comment: @AlexSilva What? http://www.ditutor.com/solid_gometry/height_pyramid.html

Comment: This problem is not the same of the link. The base is a rectangle, not a triangle.

Comment: @AlexSilva Anyway, edited.

Comment: @AlexSilva There is another problem in the link. It uses a hexagon for a base.

Comment: Clearly, VZ is not the height at all. The height is VW, and it does not depend on the base.

Comment: Thanks @AlexSilva. Btw, I removed the "center" so I don't think the question is unclear anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case, when VZ can be height of this pyramid is, when W = Z.
In this case, we will get 3 right triangles (VXZ, VYZ, XYZ).

At the given problem, height of this pyramid is clearly VW (and W does not collide with Z).